# Iterate through a dictionary provided keys are from a list

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Consider I have a list and dictionary like

```
list = ['master', 'sub1', 'sub2']
dict={'master':{'sub1':{'sub2':5}}}
```

Is there a way to iterate through a nested dictionary to get so that I can update the value stored there?

```
dict['master']['sub1']['sub2'] = new_value
```

The list of keys and new_value can vary so the solution can't be static, is there a solution to such a problem?

Using the `functools.reduce()` we can get the specific value stored within that hierarchy but I'm not quite sure how to change the value stored within that hierarchy

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion:

```
l = ['master', 'sub1', 'sub2']
d = {'master':{'sub1':{'sub2':5}}}
def to_dict(l, val=5):
  return {l[0]:val if not l[1:] else to_dict(l[1:])}

print(to_dict(l))
```

Output:

```
{'master': {'sub1': {'sub2': 5}}}
```